# Perl react to undefined in module

Tags: perl, loops, undefined, defined

I have a written a script that uses different modules.
The script a loop, returning to the beginning until it reaches a certain id and the dies.

But sometimes, the result of a module query is undefined and the script stops. In my current case:

```
Can't use an undefined value as a HASH reference at /modulepath/module.pm line xxx
```

How can I tell Perl, not to stop and skip the current processing?
I tried to use the follwing without success:

```
if (defined $var->movie( id => $imdb )){ 
#do the usual stuff 
}
else {
#skip and do nothing
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `eval` to keep code from aborting your script.

```
eval {
  # code that might blow up
};
if ($@) { 
  # it blew up, but we're still running
}
```

Comment: Why use eval when a simple defined check will suffice?

Comment: `if ( eval { $var->movie(...) } ) {` would work just as well in this case, assuming movie() returns a movie object, and not, e.g. '0'.

Comment: @darch - eval is for shielding your code from bugs in other code you don't control, however.

Answer (score 3):

Check if `$var` is defined too.

```
if (defined $var && defined $var->movie( id => $imdb )){
```

Comment: @user1121239 If you can edit the module, then you should add this to it.